# Dynamic Checkbox checked on Edit mode

Tags: angular, typescript

I am unable to checked my check boxes or switch to checked true.

please help on this i couldn't figure where i am doing wrong.

i am using Switch check boxes

i have tried *ngIf condition to show true when i get true record else false

```
    <table class="table table-stripped table-hover table-responsive-lg">
                            <thead class="thead-light">
                                <!-- <th>Id</th> -->
                                <th>Select</th>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Page Name</th>
                                <th>Page Group</th>
                                <!-- <th>Url</th> -->
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngIf="roleservice.pagelist.length==0" [class.text-danger]="!isValid && roleservice.pagelist.length==0">
                                    <td class="font-italic text-center" colspan="5">
                                        No records.
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr *ngFor="let item of roleservice.pagelist;let i=index;">
                                    <td>
                                        <div *ngIf="item.ischecked==true">
                                                <label class="switch switch-3d switch-primary">
                                                        <input type="checkbox"   [(ngModel)]="item.ischecked"   value="{{item.PageId}}" checked="true"  name = "ischecked" class="switch-input">
                                                        <span class="switch-slider"></span>
                                                    </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div *ngIf="item.ischecked==false">
                                                <label class="switch switch-3d switch-primary">
                                                        <input type="checkbox"   [(ngModel)]="item.ischecked"   value="{{item.PageId}}" checked="false"   name = "ischecked" class="switch-input">
                                                        <span class="switch-slider"></span>
                                                    </label>
                                        </div>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{item.PageId}}</td>

                                    <td>{{item.PageTitle}}</td>
                                    <td>{{item.PageGroup}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

```html
    this.roleservice.getAllRolesById(ShareVariables.RoleId).then(res => {
                this.roleservice.rolemodel = res;
                this.roleservice.pagelist = res.PageList;
                ShareVariables.RoleId = 0;
                console.log(this.roleservice.rolemodel)
                console.log(this.roleservice.pagelist)

            });
```

My browser console values [image]

Comment: If your checkbox is'nt part of a form, you may need to add [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true} , more info here : https://next.angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#options

Comment: the checkboxes are the part of form

Comment: NOT put in the input `checked=true` (or false) and use an unique input checkBox. In Angular only need `[(ngModel)]="variable"`, if variable is true, the check box is checked, else not

Comment: definitely u right , i put name property as unique

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it like this, 
put name property as unique set

```html
           <div *ngIf="item.ischecked==true">
                                                    <label class="switch switch-3d switch-primary">
                                                    
                                                            <input type="checkbox"   [(ngModel)]="item.ischecked"  checked="true"  name="ischecked{{item.PageId}}"   class="switch-input">
                                                            <span class="switch-slider"></span>
                                                        </label>
                                            </div>

                                            <div *ngIf="item.ischecked==false">
                                                    <label class="switch switch-3d switch-primary">
                                                            <input type="checkbox"   [(ngModel)]="item.ischecked"  checked="false"  name="ischecked{{item.PageId}}"     class="switch-input">
                                                            <span class="switch-slider"></span>
                                                        </label>
                                            </div>
```